# What modules should I use to create a game tree?

Tags: python, tree, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing a project for a Python coding class and I have a question.  I'm writing a [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) engine that will look several moves ahead in a game and then pick the move that it thinks is best.  While I understand that python isn't an ideal language for this (because it's not as fast as some other languages), I think that it's possible to write code that is at least functional while still maybe being a little slow.

That being said, I am in the process of trying to create two tables: a game board (think a matrix) and a game tree that will hold integers. I want to use something memory-efficient and fast to append, delete, and read entries.

The board that I am using right now is not very efficient. I wanted to ask what modules anyone would suggest (with instructions on how to use them) to write something that would make an equivalent of this but lighter on memory (examples: array, numpy; except I don't know how to use either of these):

```
self.board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0,],
              [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]
```

For the game tree I have ideas depending on how lightweight a list of lists should be.  An idea that I'm working with written in standard python is similar to:

```
tree_zero = %

tree_one =  [%, %, %]

tree_two = [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]]

tree_thre = [[[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
             [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
             [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]]],

tree_four = [[[[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
              [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
              [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]]],

             [[[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
              [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
              [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]]],

             [[[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
              [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]],
              [[%, %, %], [%, %, %], [%, %, %]]]]
```

Where each % would be one of the boards given above (and is more than ideal: not every turn has exactly three options).  But this is a slow and heavy object that is difficult for python to use memory-efficiently (especially if I go deeper than 4-ply).

If anyone has worked with programs like this before or has ideas of efficient modules to import let me know!

For an example of a game tree, think of the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree) and especially the first picture on the page.

EDIT: Ideally, I would like to look further than four moves ahead, this is just an example of how the first four levels would look.  Also, there will be multiple copies of the given trees floating around for use.  Speed is important for something that grows exponentially like this.

Comment: Since you're only looking ahead three moves, this shouldn't be extraordinarily memory intensive. Do you have any code?

Comment: You might want to check out some of the [other questions on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reversi).

Comment: Python lists are actually good objects if all you want is random access to one of its items - and lists of lists have nothing wrong per se. You could build a tree object yourself that allows you to retrieve a leaf node, or a subtree in a more readable form - but it would be ok if the internal data there is kept as a list of lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, Python is utterly perfect for this sort of work! That is, I had a tremendously fun and productive time doing AI for a board game using Python.

My first recommendation is to explore [Bit Boards](http://www.fzibi.com/cchess/bitboards.htm). Though the application example here is for chess, the concept is perfectly transferable to Reversi. Using zeroes and ones to represent the presence of pieces on a set-sized board not only has the advantage of lower memory footprint, it has the advantage of increased speed of calculating (bitwise operations are faster than equality ones).

In addition, you should redesign your model to somehow implement recursion (facilitated by a scoring function).  Such an implementation means you can write a single function and allow it to scale infinite move depth (or rather, unlimited by your design, limited only by resources) rather than anticipate and hard-code the logic for 1,2,3,4 moves.  A well-designed function to this effect works for both sides (players) and can then be halted to choose the best options that fit within a threshold (halted by any criteria you choose, positions calculated/real-time spent).

For reference, here is the github for a [board game called Thud](https://github.com/hexparrot/thudgame) I made with almost exactly the same requirements as your program. Here, I worked with a 17x17 board, three different pieces and two different strategies--which we both can see is already more complex than Reversi's rules.

Oh, and a good recursive model also accommodates multi-threading!

Comment: I'd be happy to discuss any of this with you, too--AI is a hugely entertaining pursuit!

Comment: +1 Very interesting. I'm just starting a proof of concept for a similar African traditional board game called [**Tsoro**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igisoro) and would like to develop the game AI in Python. This has really helped me coming up with the AI design, thank you so much! If you are interested I shall create a github repo for this proof of concept. Cheers!